# OWASP Dependency-Check Plugin python repo

Tags: jenkins-plugins, owasp

I was just wondering what is process of scanning python repo in OWASP Dependency-Check Plugin . I have a python repo where lots of python files are there. I have configured scanpath like /**/*.py, But I see reports like depependency-check-report.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates. Then I scanned another test repo from github and got same result. Am i missing something here? There should some reports.

Answer (score -1):

I have ended up by downloading and running cli. something like below.

```
wget http://dl.bintray.com/jeremy-long/owasp/dependency-check-3.0.2-release.zip
unzip dependency-check-3.0.2-release.zip
/home/ec2-user/dependency-check/bin/dependency-check.sh --project "Dev" --scan "/src/python" --format "XML" --disableNSP "true" --enableExperimental --disablePyDist "false" --disablePyPkg "false"
dependencyCheckPublisher canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', healthy: '0', pattern: '', unHealthy: '1000'
```